# list picker gives error when selting selected item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have a listpicker control that has a list of meals. This control is populated using following code where viewModelMeal returns a collection of type Meal

[image]

After that I get the Diet data from database and that also has a column name MealId. Now when I try to set the selected item of listpicker control with that mealid it gives me error that "SelectedItem must always be set to a valid value". Here is the function setting the selected item of listpicker

[image]

and XAML code

```
 <toolkit:ListPicker Name="lpMeal" Height="60" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Black" FullModeHeader="Select your Meal" Foreground="White" ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly" Margin="5,0">
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Name="listpickerStackpannel" >
                                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding mealId}" Visibility="Collapsed"></TextBlock>-->
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding mealName}" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Name="listpickerStackpannel" Margin="10">
                                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding mealId}" Visibility="Collapsed"></TextBlock>-->
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding mealName}" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Comment: You can only set it to an item (model) of the ItemsSource.  Not an arbitrary number.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Chubosaurus Software's comment.

You need to set the SelectedItem to a value that is in the list that the lpMeal ItemsSource is bound to. In your case:

```
lpMeal.SelectedItem = DietViewModel.GetDefault().GetItem(ID);
```

Therefore you are setting the SelectedItem to a member of the list in it's ItemsSource.

Comment: Still the same error. I understand what you are saying but the problem is listpicker populated using Meal list while diet view model returns the data of type Diet. So these are different viewmodels returning different type of collection but what I wanted to do was since Diet list has the mealId so I wanted the meal listpicker to set the selected item to that mealid.